# What is causing error in my code

Tags: oracle, plsql

Have another issue with my code and I thought I understood this one pretty well. Objective is to display a rating for a movie_id based on number of times it was rented. Am I correct in using %ROWCOUNT as test condition for the IF/ELSIF clauses in the code? So if movie_id shows up on lets say 10 rows it ranks High (declared with variable mov_flag). If I'm completely wrong please show me methods in simpler terms to understand. Thanks!

My code:

```
DECLARE 
mov_flag    VARCHAR(3); --flag for test condition   
   SELECT movie_id, movie_title 
       FROM mm_movie JOIN mm_rental
         USING (movie_id)
           WHERE movie_id = &movie_id;
BEGIN
  IF movie_id%ROWCOUNT > 35 THEN mov_flag := 'High';
    ELSIF movie_id%ROWCOUNT >= 21 THEN mov_flag := 'Mid';
      ELSIF movie_id%ROWCOUNT >= 5 THEN mov_flag := 'Low';
         ELSE mov_flag := 'Dump';
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Movie ID: ' || movie_id || 
                     'Movie title: ' || movie_title ||
                     'Movie Rating: ' || mov_flag);
END;
```

Comment: It always helps to say what error you are getting.

Comment: That's not how you declare a cursor. And even if it was, you wouldn't have run that SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ROWCOUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/sql_cursor.htm#LNPLS1211) tells you how many rows have been fetched from an implicit or explicit cursor. It would only tell you how many times a movie had been rented it you selected into a collection. You also can't put a query in the declare section unless it's part of a cursor declaration. And you need to select each column into a variable.

You want to do a simple aggregate count into a numeric variable:

```
DECLARE
  l_movie_id mm_movie.movie_id%type;
  l_movie_title mm_movie.movie_title%type;
  l_rent_count pls_integer;
  l_rating varchar2(4);
BEGIN
  SELECT mm.movie_id, mm.movie_title, count(mr.movie_id)
  INTO l_movie_id, l_movie_title, l_rent_count
  FROM mm_movie mm
  LEFT JOIN mm_rental mr
  ON mr.movie_id = mm.movie_id
  WHERE mm.movie_id = &movie_id
  GROUP BY mm.movie_id, mm.movie_title;

  IF l_rent_count > 35 THEN l_rating := 'High';
  ELSIF l_rent_count >= 21 THEN l_rating := 'Mid';
  ELSIF l_rent_count >= 5 THEN l_rating := 'Low';
  ELSE l_rating := 'Dump';
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Movie ID: ' || l_movie_id || 
                 ' Movie title: ' || l_movie_title ||
                 ' Movie Rating: ' || l_rating);
END;
```

But you shouldn't rely on dbms_output being seen by the client. It's useful for debugging, not for general display.

You can do this is plain SQL instead, using case instead of if/else:

```
SELECT mm.movie_id, mm.movie_title,
  CASE WHEN count(mr.movie_id) > 35 THEN 'HIGH'
    WHEN count(mr.movie_id) >= 21 THEN 'MED'
    WHEN count(mr.movie_id) >= 5 THEN 'LOW'
    ELSE 'DUMP'
  END AS rating
FROM mm_movie mm
LEFT JOIN mm_rental mr
ON mr.movie_id = mm.movie_id
WHERE mm.movie_id = &movie_id
GROUP BY mm.movie_id, mm.movie_title;
```

Comment: Great thanks! Not sure how to ask this (beginner) is there a method or way to look at a problem statement to identify which type of block of code to write for scenarios like this? Originally I was leaning toward Records and Cursor with FOR Loop. This is one of my biggest struggle with PL/SQL to fully understand. Books are too rigid and don't offer what a real programmer does to solve problems. Thanks again!